# Is this a case of underflow?

Tags: binary

```
0b10001111
+
0b10011000

1b00100111
```

Because we were given two positive numbers and got a negative one it is an underflow? although it is a number -128<-39 it is still called underflow?

Comment: [Underflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow). [Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).